# SQL Server 08 - pivot - Change Column Name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have this code:

```
SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT A.Id,
          B.Note,
          C.Value,
          C.Ammount
   FROM Table1 A
   LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON A.Id = B.Id
   LEFT JOIN Table3 C ON B.Id = c.Id AND B.Name = C.Name
   INNER JOIN(
      SELECT Name, LName, AxValue, Code, Number
      FROM Table Ax
      Where (Code = 80 AND Name = 'Bo') AS D ON D.AxValue = C.Value)
)AS Node1
PIVOT(
   SUM(Ammount)
   FOR Value IN ([1], [2])
)AS Node2
```

and the result is something like this:

```
Id   Note   1    2
--------------------
01   ok    500  100
```

Is there any way to rename the last two columns with names(Ex1,Ex2) instead of numbers(1,2)?

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
SELECT * FROM(
...
```

By

```
SELECT Id, Note, [1] as Ex1, [2] as Ex2 FROM(
...
```

It is always better to replace `*` by the columns you need. You can alias them with `as`.

You can find more information here: [Using Table Aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

And here under `column_ alias`: [SELECT Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, Note, [1] as Ex1, [2] as Ex2 FROM(
   SELECT A.Id,
          B.Note,
          C.Value,
          C.Ammount
   FROM Table1 A
   LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON A.Id = B.Id
   LEFT JOIN Table3 C ON B.Id = c.Id AND B.Name = C.Name
   INNER JOIN(
      SELECT Name, LName, AxValue, Code, Number
      FROM Table Ax
      Where (Code = 80 AND Name = 'Bo') AS D ON D.AxValue = C.Value)
)AS Node1
PIVOT(
   SUM(Ammount)
   FOR Value IN ([1], [2])
)AS Node2
```

Instead of using `*` you need to specify the name of your column.

Comment: When i run this i get the error: The multi-part identifier "A.ID" could not be bound. (and so for the others allias)